# Creating EC2 security group with existing VPC using AWS-CDK2-Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an EC2 security group in an existing VPC with Python AWS CDK2 . Here my code,

```
 ec2securitygroup = ec2.CfnSecurityGroup(
            self,
            "EC2SecurityGroup2",
            group_description="Security group for ec2",
            group_name="test-security-group",
            tags=[
                {
                    "key": "Name",
                    "value": "test-security-group"
                }
            ],
            vpc_id="vpc-1234567",
            security_group_ingress=[
                {
                    "cidr_ip": "10.0.0.0/16",
                    "description": "Allow all internal traffic from VPC1",
                    "ip_protocol": "-1"
                },
                {
                    "source_security_group_id": "sg-123456789",
                    "source_security_group_owner_id": "123456789",
                    "from_port": 80,
                    "ip_protocol": "tcp",
                    "to_port": 80
                }
            ],
            security_group_egress=[
                {
                    "cidr_ip": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "description": "Allow outbound traffic",
                    "ip_protocol": "-1"
                }
            ]
        )
```

I am getting the following error

jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
@jsii/kernel.SerializationError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnSecurityGroup: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnSecurityGroupProps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how the CDK works and the fact that it's translated from TypeScript via jsii. If you want to use plain Python dicts in lieu of interfaces, you have to use the original field names, not the ones translated to Python:

```py
ec2securitygroup = ec2.CfnSecurityGroup(
    self,
    "EC2SecurityGroup2",
    group_description="Security group for ec2",
    group_name="test-security-group",
    tags=[{"key": "Name", "value": "test-security-group"}],
    vpc_id="vpc-1234567",
    security_group_ingress=[
        {
            "cidrIp": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "description": "Allow all internal traffic from VPC1",
            "ipProtocol": "-1",
        },
        {
            "sourceSecurityGroupId": "sg-123456789",
            "sourceSecurityGroupOwnerId": "123456789",
            "fromPort": 80,
            "ipProtocol": "tcp",
            "toPort": 80,
        },
    ],
    security_group_egress=[
        {
            "cidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "description": "Allow outbound traffic",
            "ipProtocol": "-1",
        }
    ],
)
```

To be able to use the translated snake_case field name, you have to use the generated classes:

```py
ec2securitygroup = ec2.CfnSecurityGroup(
    self,
    "EC2SecurityGroup2",
    group_description="Security group for ec2",
    group_name="test-security-group",
    tags=[{"key": "Name", "value": "test-security-group"}],
    vpc_id="vpc-1234567",
    security_group_ingress=[
        ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty(
            cidr_ip="10.0.0.0/16",
            description="Allow all internal traffic from VPC1",
            ip_protocol="-1",
        ),
        ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty(
            source_security_group_id="sg-123456789",
            source_security_group_owner_id="123456789",
            from_port=80,
            ip_protocol="tcp",
            to_port=80,
        ),
    ],
    security_group_egress=[
        ec2.CfnSecurityGroup.EgressProperty(
            cidr_ip="0.0.0.0/0",
            description="Allow outbound traffic",
            ip_protocol="-1",
        )
    ],
)
```

A much better solution is to use the L2 construct, though:

```py
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_vpc_attributes(
    self,
    "Vpc2",
    vpc_id="vpc-1234567",
    availability_zones=["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"],
)
ec2securitygroup = ec2.SecurityGroup(
    self,
    "EC2SecurityGroup",
    vpc=vpc,
    security_group_name="test-security-group",
    description="Security group for ec2",
    allow_all_outbound=True,
)
ec2securitygroup.add_ingress_rule(
    peer=ec2.Peer.ipv4("10.0.0.0/16"),
    connection=ec2.Port.all_traffic(),
    description="Allow all internal traffic from VPC1",
)
ec2securitygroup.connections.allow_from(
    other=ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, "other", "sg-1234567"),
    port_range=ec2.Port.tcp(80),
)

cdk.Tags.of(ec2securitygroup).add("Name", "test-security-group")
```

Everything becomes easier when you have everything defined using L2, including your VPCs and instances.

Dealing with security groups directly is actually [advised against in the CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.html), since it provides useful abstractions that make it an implementation detail, namely the `ec2.Connections` class that all `ec2.IConnectable` (like `ec2.Instance`) expose:

> Direct manipulation of the Security Group through addIngressRule and addEgressRule is possible, but mutation through the .connections object is recommended. If you peer two constructs with security groups this way, appropriate rules will be created in both.

More documentation on this feature is available in the general aws-ec2 module overview docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#allowing-connections